# How can I copy the link in Google without openning the link and the "Google stuff" in the URL?

Tags: web, hyperlink

I want to copy a link in Google without opening that link and without the *"Google stuff"*.

[image: Copy Link in Google]

When I use my browser by right-clicking the link and selecting *Copy Link Location*, it copies a very long link because of the *Google stuff*.

```
http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FC%2F0%2FA%2FC0AEF0CC-B969-406D-989A-4CDAFDBB3F3C%2FWin8_UXG_RTM.pdf&ei=1bWHULCyEZGQiQfl_IGIDA&usg=AFQjCNEtK1uai68ZKixTovFm2bwe7C9LGg&sig2=cPFFl4ARTTr7xHTHcr5k8A
```

I just want the `download.microsoft.com/.../C/0/A/.../Win8_UXG_RTM.pdf` URL, but I can't see it in my browser even after opening the site with Google.

Comment: I came across the same problem this morning and noticed that `Bing` doesn't prefix or code links with redirector stuff.

Comment: See: [Turning off Google search results indirection](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22291/turning-off-google-search-results-indirection) on [webapps.se]

Comment: Hi, you can use the Google/Yandex search link fix plugin for firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix/?src=cb-dl-hotness)

or Don't track me google for chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg?hl=en)

I got the info from http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/copy-crapfree-urls-googles-search-results/

Comment: See [this best answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40834/65574) - requires no scripts, no going to other websites or anything.

Answer (score 10):

Simple. Take the url param of the google redirector link (copy link in the browser and paste it to any text editor), it's a string after `url=` and before first `&` symbol (bolded out):

> http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=**http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FC%2F0%2FA%2FC0AEF0CC-B969-406D-989A-4CDAFDBB3F3C%2FWin8_UXG_RTM.pdf**&ei=1bWHULCyEZGQiQfl_IGIDA&usg=AFQjCNEtK1uai68ZKixTovFm2bwe7C9LGg&sig2=cPFFl4ARTTr7xHTHcr5k8A

`http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FC%2F0%2FA%2FC0AEF0CC-B969-406D-989A-4CDAFDBB3F3C%2FWin8_UXG_RTM.pdf` is a URL-encoded URI.

You can use [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to decode it to `http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/A/C0AEF0CC-B969-406D-989A-4CDAFDBB3F3C/Win8_UXG_RTM.pdf`

Comment: A lot of trouble to go through for just getting a target link. Several automated solutions exist: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/copy-crapfree-urls-googles-search-results/

Answer (score 3):

For this one online tool is available see [here](http://industrystandardsoftware.com/online_tools/converters/convert-serp-link-to-direct-location-for-copying-and-pasting.htm)

just paste the long `url` and it will give the normal url

For more detail you can refer this [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31028/google-copy-link-location-annoyance)

Comment: Brilliant solution, similar to Petr Abdulins solution but wrapped up in a tool for you!